# Make two corner rounded and two straight cut instead of curve in flutter

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout, flutter-web

[image]

How can I make below tile like design in flutter, two sides are little curved and rest of the two side are straight cut with soft curve. I can make two rounded corners and two unrounded, but unable to make like below one. Anyone know how to make tile like this. I have used RoundRect, ClipRRect and Container but unable to make Widget like this. Any help will be appreciable.

Thanks for your time and effort in advance.

Comment: make a custom `ShapeBorder` class, exactly like `RoundedRectangleBorder` or `BeveledRectangleBorder` are made

Comment: Can you provide a code snippet. I think, I have tried with this also.

Comment: https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/painting/RoundedRectangleBorder-class.html there is a small blue icon next to "RoundedRectangleBorder class" label, click on it, do the same for `BeveledRectangleBorder`

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Here's how you do it:

```
            Material(
              clipBehavior: Clip.antiAlias,
              shape: BeveledRectangleBorder(
                 // side: BorderSide(color: Colors.blue), if you need
                  borderRadius: BorderRadius.only(
                      topLeft: Radius.circular(20.0),
                      bottomRight: Radius.circular(20.0))),
              child: Container(
                height: 100,
                width: 100,
               decoration: BoxDecoration(
                          color: Colors.red,
                          borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(15.0),
                        ),
              ),
            ),
```

Here is the code of the image you provided if you need to implement it:

```
            Row(
              children: <Widget>[
                Expanded(
                  child: Padding(
                    padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
                    child: Material(
                      clipBehavior: Clip.antiAlias,
                      shape: BeveledRectangleBorder(
                          borderRadius: BorderRadius.only(
                              topLeft: Radius.circular(20.0),
                              bottomRight: Radius.circular(20.0))),
                      child: Container(
                        height: 100,
                        decoration: BoxDecoration(
                          color: Colors.blue,
                          borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(15.0),
                        ),
                      ),
                    ),
                  ),
                ),
                Expanded(
                  child: Padding(
                    padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
                    child: Material(
                      clipBehavior: Clip.antiAlias,
                      shape: BeveledRectangleBorder(
                          borderRadius: BorderRadius.only(
                              topLeft: Radius.circular(20.0),
                              bottomRight: Radius.circular(20.0))),
                      child: Container(
                        height: 100,
                        decoration: BoxDecoration(
                          color: Colors.black,
                          borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(15.0),
                        ),
                      ),
                    ),
                  ),
                ),
                Expanded(
                  child: Padding(
                    padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
                    child: Material(
                      clipBehavior: Clip.antiAlias,
                      shape: BeveledRectangleBorder(
                          borderRadius: BorderRadius.only(
                              topLeft: Radius.circular(20.0),
                              bottomRight: Radius.circular(20.0))),
                      child: Container(
                        height: 100,
                        decoration: BoxDecoration(
                          color: Colors.red,
                          borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(15.0),
                        ),
                      ),
                    ),
                  ),
                ),
              ],
            ),
```

Comment: You are using two layers, That's what I am missing. Thanks, for your time.