# Create a Flutter TextFormField with two corners rounded and two straight cut corners

Tags: flutter

Is is possible to create a TextFormField in Flutter with two rounded corners and then two corners that are cut straight like you can see in this image?

This can be done using the `Material` widget for regular shape creation as [demonstrated here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60564544/make-two-corner-rounded-and-two-straight-cut-instead-of-curve-in-flutter). In the `InputDecoration` widget I'm not seeing a way to do corners anything other than rounded, unless this can be accomplished with the [InputDecorator class](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/material/InputDecorator-class.html)?

**Current InputDecoration constant for my unique TextFormField border:**

```
const InputDecoration kInputStringFields = InputDecoration(
  hintStyle: TextStyle(
    fontFamily: kBarlowFont,
    fontSize: 16.0,
  ),
  fillColor: kInputStringFieldColor,
  filled: true,
  contentPadding: EdgeInsets.only(left: 20.0),
  border: OutlineInputBorder(
    borderRadius: BorderRadius.only(
      topLeft: Radius.elliptical(8.0, 8.0),
      topRight: Radius.circular(20.0),
      bottomLeft: Radius.circular(20.0),
      bottomRight: Radius.elliptical(0.0, 0.0),
    ),
    borderSide: BorderSide.none,
  ),
);
```

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As per your [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60564544/make-two-corner-rounded-and-two-straight-cut-instead-of-curve-in-flutter) provide I tried something like that try below code hope its help to you.

```
 Material(
        clipBehavior: Clip.antiAlias,
        shape: BeveledRectangleBorder(
          borderRadius: BorderRadius.only(
            topLeft: Radius.circular(20.0),
            bottomRight: Radius.circular(20.0),
          ),
        ),
        child: Container(
          decoration: BoxDecoration(
            color: Colors.grey[300],
            borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(
              15.0,
            ),
          ),
          child: TextFormField(
            decoration: InputDecoration(
              prefixIcon: Icon(Icons.search),
              hintText: 'Search The Store',
              border: OutlineInputBorder(),
              focusedBorder: InputBorder.none,
            ),
          ),
        ),
      ),
```

Your result screen like-> [image]

Comment: Yep, the Material route seems to be the only option that I can find. Thanks.

Comment: Welcome ,Glad to help you .

Comment: Where https://i.imgur.com/F2p7orb.png is the white around the rounded corners coming from? Need bg around corners to be transparent. Straight edges are getting clipBehavior.

Comment: Material(color: Colors.transparent,

Comment: Your problem is solved or what was the error

Comment: @ravindra-s-patil see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69472003/add-a-border-to-an-atypical-flutter-material-widget-shape-after-it-paints where I'm expanding this atypical shape and need to add a border. Would appreciate your input.