# How can i make this shape in Flutter

Tags: flutter, dart

[image]

I am trying to make this shape in Flutter but i could not get it, I tried to use border radius but i am getting the round shape from outside rather than from inside

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60564544/make-two-corner-rounded-and-two-straight-cut-instead-of-curve-in-flutter

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With a little bit of math and lots of numbers, you can define a `Path` for your shape:

```dart
final path = Path()
  ..moveTo(w * 0.27, size.height * 0.29)
  ..cubicTo(w * 0.40, h * 0.29, w * 0.40, h * 0.29, w * 0.44, h * 0.29)
  [...]
  ..cubicTo(w * 0.25, h * 0.29, w * 0.25, h * 0.29, w * 0.27, h * 0.29)
  ..close();
```

**Remark:** If you don't want to work the maths out by yourself, check the [Flutter Shape Maker](https://fluttershapemaker.com/), by [RetroPortal Studio](https://www.youtube.com/retroportalstudio).

And then use draw your `Path` thanks to a `CustomPainter`.

## Full code sample

[image]

```dart
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(const MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  const MyApp({Key? key}) : super(key: key);
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      theme: ThemeData.light(),
      home: const HomePage(),
    );
  }
}

class HomePage extends StatelessWidget {
  const HomePage({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: CustomPaint(
        painter: MyPainter(),
        child: const SizedBox(
          width: 1000,
          height: 300,
          child: Text('pan'),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}

class MyPainter extends CustomPainter {
  @override
  void paint(Canvas canvas, Size size) {
    final w = size.width;
    final h = size.height;
    final strokeWidth = size.longestSide / 80;

    final strokePaint = Paint()
      ..color = const Color(0xFF514890)
      ..style = PaintingStyle.stroke
      ..strokeWidth = strokeWidth;

    final fillPaint = Paint()
      ..color = const Color(0xFF830B2C)
      ..style = PaintingStyle.fill;

    final path = Path()
      ..moveTo(w * 0.27, size.height * 0.29)
      ..cubicTo(w * 0.40, h * 0.29, w * 0.40, h * 0.29, w * 0.44, h * 0.29)
      ..cubicTo(w * 0.46, h * 0.29, w * 0.46, h * 0.29, w * 0.48, h * 0.31)
      ..cubicTo(w * 0.52, h * 0.38, w * 0.61, h * 0.51, w * 0.66, h * 0.57)
      ..cubicTo(w * 0.67, h * 0.58, w * 0.67, h * 0.58, w * 0.67, h * 0.60)
      ..cubicTo(w * 0.67, h * 0.60, w * 0.67, h * 0.61, w * 0.67, h * 0.61)
      ..cubicTo(w * 0.67, h * 0.64, w * 0.67, h * 0.64, w * 0.65, h * 0.64)
      ..cubicTo(w * 0.55, h * 0.64, w * 0.36, h * 0.64, w * 0.27, h * 0.64)
      ..cubicTo(w * 0.25, h * 0.64, w * 0.25, h * 0.64, w * 0.25, h * 0.61)
      ..cubicTo(w * 0.25, h * 0.54, w * 0.25, h * 0.39, w * 0.25, h * 0.31)
      ..cubicTo(w * 0.25, h * 0.29, w * 0.25, h * 0.29, w * 0.27, h * 0.29)
      ..close();

    canvas.drawPath(path, strokePaint);
    canvas.drawPath(path, fillPaint);
  }

  @override
  bool shouldRepaint(covariant CustomPainter oldDelegate) {
    return true;
  }
}
```